# Where is an inputShape in tf.keras.layers.Conv2D()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am writing a simple CNN model for classic digit recognition task. Part of my code looks like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
image_width = 28
image_height = 28
image_channels = 1

model.add(layers.Conv2D(
    8,
    5,
    inputShape = [image_width, image_height, image_channels],
    strides = 1,
    activation = 'relu',
    kernelInitializer = 'varianceScaling'
));
```

where imports are:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

The current is this model layer marked as wrong by a compiler with error message `keyword argument is not understood: inputShape`

I am refering this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html#5 where `inputShape` is presented, but on another hand the latest tf docs indeed don't have this argument https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D.

There are many breaking changes in API over passed 5 years, so existing answers on SO or other resources don't really bridge this gap in docs and I have to ask for your help with this issue.

Could you suggest where is this parameter go and how the `Conv2D` layer should look like without `inputShape`?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of TF are you using vs the codelab?

Comment: @SurajShourie, tf version is 2.14.0

Comment: You can provide as kwarg with `input_shape`. Changing to `model.add(layers.Conv2D(
    8,
    5,
    input_shape = [image_width, image_height, image_channels],
    strides = 1,
    activation = 'relu',
    kernelInitializer = 'varianceScaling'
));` should work

Comment: You were looking at a JavaScript API documentation, and wondered why it did not work in Python? The answers should be obvious if you check the python documentation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, indeed I used ```tf``` codelab on ```js``` for reference, but documentation I used is for python - it also doesn't have any mention about ```inputShape```. Naming conventions might be different, but API contract should be the same.

Comment: @Gleichmut There is no contract, these Javascript APIs for Keras/TensorFlow do not follow the exact same API as in Python.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, yes, sometimes this happens. Thank you. Regarding contract of method I mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract#Description, so at least method's input and output parameters represent a contract of this method.

Comment: I know what a contract is, my point is that there is nothing enforcing them in these APIs.

Comment: Got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be `input_shape` instead of `inputShape`. The kernel initializer argument also needs to be [updated](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/). You need to [replace](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/#variancescaling-class) `kernelInitializer` and `'varianceScaling'` like the following:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(
    8,
    5,
    input_shape = [image_width, image_height, image_channels],
    strides = 1,
    activation = 'relu',
    kernel_initializer = 'variance_scaling' 
));
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain to me why official docs don't have ```input_shape``` within a contract of this class? It is mentioned in examples, but not within the contract. Doesn't mean it is something optional supplied via ```varargs``` and the layer generally works without it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "contract of class", but it's pretty straightforward - JS uses camelCase for variables (and other stuff), and python uses snake_case. To overwrite the snake_case convention of python to fit the convention for JS in python arguments would be a very strange move. Also, the parameters and its names are clearly listed in the documentation pages for the layers.

Comment: @Gleichmut, yes, the `input_shape` argument is optional given that it's not the first layer of the network or the input_shape is defined via the [Input](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/) object. However, if you use it as the first layer, you'd need to define the `input_shape` as mentioned in the [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/).